# Android fragments on itemclick (listview)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I want to have an activity, where in it's layout I will have a listview with fixed content (array) and on the right side I want dynamic content (so I decided: fragments).
My MainLayout is like this (activity_vizitarea.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ro.softwarex.bellaapp.procesarevizita.app.VizitareaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@id/id_vizita_jobs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@id/id_fragment_container"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The last LinearLayout will hold the fragments

My Activity looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VizitareaActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vizitarea);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_vizita_jobs);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "First category",
                "Second category",
                "Third category",
                "Fourth category",
                " and so on",
                "Last category"
        };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                int itemPosition     = position;
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vizitarea, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And a fragment looks like this:

```
public class FirsCatFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_firstcat_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

and it's layout is something like this (fragment_firstcat_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So my behavior should be: onClick of a category from the listView, a corresponding fragment should be loaded... But I have no idea on how to implement this.

I imagine it to be somewhere in onItemClick, a case or an if statement checking the position of the clicked item, and based on that number, decide which fragment to bring up.
But I do not seem to get how this work. I checked multiple tutorials on the web but I cannot seem to be able to make it work.

The principle of the activity is similar to the Settings page in iOS (only for Android). Like in this image:

[image]

I know there is NavigationDrawer but it is not recommended for less than 3 top level elements. I only want 2 levels: master and detail, the category and the details of the category. That is all.

Can you please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For left side list view you can go for `Navigation Drawer` and load list view on navigation drawer. and load related fragment on frame layout. Follow this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

check this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/replace-fragment.html

here in main layout having FrameLayout called `maincontainer`
Inside onitem click of your list view do like this:

```
MyFragment1 fragment = (MyFragment1)myFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_1);

    if (fragment == null) {


     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer, myFragment1, TAG_1);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }else{

     fragment.setMsg("MyFragment1 already loaded");
    }
   }});
```

Every time `maincontainer` replacing with new fragments.

Comment: "Use the navigation drawer if you have more than 3 unique top-level views. If not, use fixed tabs for top-level organization to ease discovery and interaction." This is from https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Is there no solution for what I want? ListView + fragments?

Comment: I suggested for mobile. If you working with tablet then fix width of your left list view like: android:layout_width="200dp" and remaining place put your layout for fragments.

Comment: I do not have a problem building the layout. I have a problem showing the fragments. And yes. I want to do this for tablets only. So I do not need auto-hiding menu (slide)

Comment: Loading/Replacing fragments into layout?

Comment: Any chance you can tell me how to adapt that tutorial to my code above?

Comment: Nevermind. I chose to use a listview to display categories and a linearlayout that gets populated with fragments on listView ItemClick. Since Lokesh was the only one available to try and help me solve my problem, I will award his answer.